# How to create new commands that you can run after running the sbt command Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to run certain tasks and startup servers after running `sbt`. I want to be able to run commands in terminal to do this. How can I define them? Are plugins the right way to do this:

I see some code like this:

```
object DoThing extends AutoPlugin {
  object autoImport {
    val vpnCheck = taskKey[Boolean]("Check for a VPN connection.")
  }
  import autoImport._

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    vpnCheck := {
      doVpnCheck()
    }
  )
```

What is the projectSettings method doing? Are plugins the way?

From the plugins page:

> A plugin is a way to use external code in a build definition. A plugin can be a library used to implement a task (you might use Knockoff to write a markdown processing task). A plugin can define a sequence of sbt settings that are automatically added to all projects or that are explicitly declared for selected projects. For example, a plugin might add a proguard task and associated (overridable) settings. Finally, a plugin can define new commands (via the commands setting).

But I can't seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario, maybe you can just a create **Task** in **sbt** file to do this, like:

```
val hello = taskKey[Unit]("hello world")

hello := {
  println("hello")
}
```

and if you run it automatically in **startup time**, you can create [.sbtrc](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Best-Practices.html#.sbtrc) file in project directory, and it like:

```
alias boot = ;reload ;hello ;iflast shell
```